# Problem when compiling with codes from asymptote (order of graphs)

Tags: compiling, asymptote, compilation-error

```
\documentclass[12pt, UTF8, scheme = plain]{ctexart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{asydef}
size(6cm);
\end{asydef}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
%%
%%
\begin{enumerate}

\item %%%% problematic one in 3D

This will be produced only when it is by itself.

\begin{center}
\begin{asy}
import graph3;
import solids;
real r=(3+sqrt(5))/2;
real s=sqrt(r);
real Brad=r;
real brad=1;
real Fht = 2*s;
currentprojection=orthographic(1,0,.2);
currentlight=(10,10,5);
unitsize(0.1cm);
revolution sph=sphere((0,0,Fht/2),Fht/2);
// draw(surface(sph),green+white+opacity(0.5));
// triple f(pair t) {return (t.x*cos(t.y),t.x*sin(t.y),t.x^(1/n)*sin(t.y/n));}
triple f(pair t) {
triple v0 = Brad*(cos(t.x),sin(t.x),0);
triple v1 = brad*(cos(t.x),sin(t.x),0)+(0,0,Fht);
return (v0 + t.y*(v1-v0));
}
triple g(pair t) {
return (t.y*cos(t.x),t.y*sin(t.x),0);
}
surface sback=surface(f,(3pi/4,0),(7pi/4,1),80,2);
surface sfront=surface(f,(7pi/4,0),(11pi/4,1),80,2);
surface base = surface(g,(0,0),(2pi,Brad),80,2);
draw(sback,gray(0.9));
draw(sfront,gray(0.5));
draw(base,gray(0.9));
draw(surface(sph),gray(0.4));
\end{asy}
\end{center}

what I mean is, if I put the one at the end back to item 2,
the document would not produce the 3D graph in item 1.
Why is that the case??




\end{enumerate}
%%
%%
\end{document}
%%
%%
\item 
%%%% if this is Item 2 - neither graph would compile - only asy files are produced.
%%%% only works when it is item 1 (but then the 3D graph would not be produced)!!!
\begin{center}
\begin{asy}
unitsize(0.15cm);
fill((0,0)--(2,0)--(2,26)--(0,26)--cycle,gray);
fill((6,0)--(8,0)--(8,26)--(6,26)--cycle,gray);
fill((12,0)--(14,0)--(14,26)--(12,26)--cycle,gray);
fill((18,0)--(20,0)--(20,26)--(18,26)--cycle,gray);
fill((24,0)--(26,0)--(26,26)--(24,26)--cycle,gray);
fill((0,0)--(26,0)--(26,2)--(0,2)--cycle,gray);
fill((0,12)--(26,12)--(26,14)--(0,14)--cycle,gray);
fill((0,24)--(26,24)--(26,26)--(0,26)--cycle,gray);
\end{asy}
\end{center}
```

When compiled with (in ```Notepad++`)

```
pdflatex $(NAME_PART).tex
asy -v $(NAME_PART)-*.asy
pdflatex $(NAME_PART).tex
pdflatex $(NAME_PART).tex
```

It would produced a final pdf, correctly with a 3D picture.
[image]

But if I put the **item2** back, neither graph would show.

And if I put the **item2** as **item1** (before the 3D code), the 2D picture can be produced, but not the 3D figure.
[image]

Why? and how could I fix it?
so that both can be compiled and produced into a single PDF file.

Comment: With standard `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`
both items shows up fine.
Have you considered to make a standalone pictures
and include them as the images?
Imho, while using the `asymptote` code in the LaTeX document 
is a nice option, it leads to increased complexity
and hence - multiplies the number of possible errors,
so in most cases it is much simpler to separate images from the text,
unless the images are somehow deeply interwoven with the surrounding text.

Comment: @g.kov hmmmmm nor did `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` work for me. It came up with texts only..... I am using MikTeX. What TeX distribution are you using ???

Comment: Tried to use MikTeX long time ago, faced with a lot of troubles,
switched to TeXLive and happily use it ever after.

Comment: @g.kov Hmmm, I thought they are just different distrbutions and the packages are suppose to function exactly the same??

Comment: Yes, they should. In theory...